# #error You now need to define either FIXED_POINT or FLOATING_POINT

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, compilation, speex

I am trying to compile ioauek3 on our IBM PowerPC machine that is running with a Linux environment.
I got this error:

```
#error You now need to define either FIXED_POINT or FLOATING_POINT
```

After searching the net for an answer, I found many point to doing a "make speex-reconf".
I downloaded:
http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/speex/speex-1.2rc1.tar.gz

I unpacked it. Then, ran a "make". Since, I have no "install" privileges, I just ran a "make".
Then, I did a "make speex-reconf".
I got a load of output.

I went back to my ioquake3 folder, and did another "make". But, still the error wouldn't go away.
What am I missing here?

--

```
rmc104:~/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/zzz/speex-1.2rc1[8053]% make -speex-reconf
make: invalid option -- 'x'
make: invalid option -- '-'
make: invalid option -- 'c'
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
Options:
  -b, -m                      Ignored for compatibility.
  -B, --always-make           Unconditionally make all targets.
  -C DIRECTORY, --directory=DIRECTORY
                              Change to DIRECTORY before doing anything.
  -d                          Print lots of debugging information.
  --debug[=FLAGS]             Print various types of debugging information.
  -e, --environment-overrides
                              Environment variables override makefiles.
  -f FILE, --file=FILE, --makefile=FILE
                              Read FILE as a makefile.
  -h, --help                  Print this message and exit.
  -i, --ignore-errors         Ignore errors from commands.
  -I DIRECTORY, --include-dir=DIRECTORY
                              Search DIRECTORY for included makefiles.
  -j [N], --jobs[=N]          Allow N jobs at once; infinite jobs with no arg.
  -k, --keep-going            Keep going when some targets can't be made.
  -l [N], --load-average[=N], --max-load[=N]
                              Don't start multiple jobs unless load is below N.
  -L, --check-symlink-times   Use the latest mtime between symlinks and target.
  -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
                              Don't actually run any commands; just print them.
  -o FILE, --old-file=FILE, --assume-old=FILE
                              Consider FILE to be very old and don't remake it.
  -p, --print-data-base       Print make's internal database.
  -q, --question              Run no commands; exit status says if up to date.
  -r, --no-builtin-rules      Disable the built-in implicit rules.
  -R, --no-builtin-variables  Disable the built-in variable settings.
  -s, --silent, --quiet       Don't echo commands.
  -S, --no-keep-going, --stop
                              Turns off -k.
  -t, --touch                 Touch targets instead of remaking them.
  -v, --version               Print the version number of make and exit.
  -w, --print-directory       Print the current directory.
  --no-print-directory        Turn off -w, even if it was turned on implicitly.
  -W FILE, --what-if=FILE, --new-file=FILE, --assume-new=FILE
                              Consider FILE to be infinitely new.
  --warn-undefined-variables  Warn when an undefined variable is referenced.

This program built for powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu
Report bugs to <bug-make@gnu.org>

# Make data base, printed on Wed Nov  2 14:21:21 2011

# Variables

# environment
LC_CTYPE = C
# environment
CVSEDITOR = emacs -nw
# environment
XMODIFIERS = @im=kinput2
# environment
SHELL = /bin/zsh
# environment
TZ = JST-9
# environment
_ = /usr/bin/make
# environment
SSH_CONNECTION = 133.9.80.9 59052 133.9.80.16 22
# environment
PATH = /home7/yasir/bin/common:/home7/yasir/bin/ppc64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/games:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
# environment
SSH_TTY = /dev/pts/0
# default
.FEATURES := target-specific order-only second-expansion else-if archives jobserver check-symlink
# environment
PWD = /home7/yasir/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/zzz/speex-1.2rc1
# environment
HOME = /home7/yasir
# environment
CVSROOT = /usr/local/cvsroot
# environment
LOGNAME = yasir
# environment
PRINTER = ls7
# environment
LC_TIME = C
# environment
SHLVL = 1
# environment
JSERVER = razzie04
# environment
USER = yasir
# environment
OLDPWD = /home7/yasir/minoru/cfe2/yasirTemp/ioquake3dev/zzz/speex-1.2rc1/include
# default
.VARIABLES :=
# environment
CVS_RSH = ssh
# environment
SSH_CLIENT = 133.9.80.9 59052 22
# environment
MAIL = /var/mail/yasir
# environment
EDITOR = vi
# environment
LC_ALL = C
# environment
http_proxy = http://133.9.80.129:3128/
# environment
LANG = C
# environment
TERM = xterm
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=29/1024=3%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/36=3%

# Pattern-specific Variable Values

# No pattern-specific variable values.

# Directories


# No files, no impossibilities in 0 directories.

# Implicit Rules

# No implicit rules.

# Files

# files hash-table stats:
# Load=0/1024=0%, Rehash=0, Collisions=0/0=0%
# VPATH Search Paths

# No `vpath' search paths.

# No general (`VPATH' variable) search path.

# # of strings in strcache: 0
# # of strcache buffers: 0
# strcache size: total = 0 / max = 0 / min = 4096 / avg = 0
# strcache free: total = 0 / max = 0 / min = 4096 / avg = 0

# 

Finished Make data base on Wed Nov  2 14:21:21 2011
```

--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show is the result of running:

```
make -speex-reconf
```

You did not want the dash in front of that; you should have typed:

```
make speex-reconf
```

Whether that would be sufficient is a wholly separate issue.